# How to change font color of subtitles in totem movie player

Tags: totem, subtitle

Is there a way to change the font color, not the size,  of subtitles in totem movie player?

I would like to change the color to some kind of yellow so there is more contrast between the movie and the subtitles.

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't think so. Totem uses the "Pango" font description in order to specify the font to be used in the subtitles, and Pango doesn't include color as a parameter. The values you may change are "[FAMILY-LIST] [STYLE-OPTIONS] [SIZE]". Please check https://developer.gnome.org/pygtk/stable/class-pangofontdescription.html. Valid representations are: "sans bold 12", "serif,monospace bold italic condensed 16", or "normal 10". I use stock Totem in Ubuntu Gnome version 16.04.4, but since Totem has been rewritten or rebuilt with different names and frontends, I couldn't tell about other versions or spins.